# Nesting with two levels in scss not working

Tags: html, css, sass

Let's say I have a page which displays emotion and the corresponding text for it.
I wanted to change color of text based on the type of emotion. I've followed nesting inside text class but that [didn't apply the styles mentioned for the text alone](https://codepen.io/shiva3/pen/bGvBqLz). Is there any way to do this?

```css
.emotion{
  display: flex;
  &__text {
    outline: 1px solid blue; // Not applied
    &--happy{
      color: rebeccapurple
    }
    &--sad{
      color: yellow
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emotion">
  <span class="emotion__text--happy">
    Happy
  </span>
<!--   <span className="emotion__text__sad"></span>
  <span className="emotion__text__tears"></span>
  <span className="emotion__text__joy"></span> -->
  <span class="emotion__happy"> 
    
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working! just fine for me. `&__text` will not work because you don't have any specific class `.emotion__text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SCSS:

```
.emotion { &__text { outline: 1px solid blue; } }
```

means the same as this CSS:

```
.emotion__text { outline: 1px solid blue; }
```

And the class selector `.emotion__text` means:

✅ **Elements which are members of the `emotion__text` class**.

You don't have any elements that match.

You have an element with `class="emotion"` and one with `class="emotion__text--happy"` but **not** `class="emotion__text"`

It doesn't mean:

❌ **Elements which are members of any class which starts with `emotion__text`**.

---

You could add that class to an element:

```
class="emotion__text emotion__text--happy"
```

Comment: you mentioned in your answer "You don't have any elements that match", but the '&__text' in the css is like having the class '.emotion__text' isn't that right?

Comment: @Akis — It's like having the CSS class **selector** `.emotion__text`. You have no **HTML** elements which are members of the `emotion__text` class.

Comment: @Quenty thanks for clarifying, I just saw the 'outlined' in the css. I thought the issue was with the color only.